# How do i create navigation links like this in wordpress?

Tags: urls, navigation

[image]

[image]

Currently, I am using an Avada Theme and I would like this navigation to be in the shop and product pages.

Comment: Those are called breadcrumbs

Comment: @TomJNowell, Thank you so much! I am just a beginner and I was wondering what exactly is it called :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup bread crumbs for the site.

this is a link from the avada documentation that tells exactly how to do it.

https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/header/setting-up-the-page-title-bar/

Comment: Glad to help!  Would you mind marking as answered by clicking the check on the left of my answer?